# Excel - How to create a formula to return a cell to the right of the result of another formula

Tags: vba, excel

Basically, I have this formula in a cell to return the very first non 0 value in a row:

`=INDEX('Financials Cashflow Year'!C30:M30,MATCH(TRUE,INDEX('Financials Cashflow Year'!C30:M30<>0,),0))`

I would like a formula to return the value of the cell on the right of the one picked up by this very first formula.

Say we have sheet 1 first row:

```
0 0 0 4 3 2
```

Sheet 2 I would like to see with the formulas. Something scalable.

```
4 3 2
```

Comment: Can you use the same INDEX() function, but with the column_number changed?

Comment: @D.R. I think he wants all cells to the right (based on the example having 6 columns and the output are rows 4-6), which would need a bit more code than that, but that's definitely a simple and great solution for the written question/title.

Comment: @Daniel_Coutinho, do you have a fixed number of columns, or how does the data sit?  Unsure if you want a dynamic range to work with, or if you can deal with with a fixed range of 6 columns, like the example.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll want an Array Formula for this. Instead of the match use a SMALL function to get the item you want, something like this:

```
={INDEX('Financials Cashflow Year'!$C30:$M30,1,SMALL(IF('Financials Cashflow Year'!$C30:$M30>0,COLUMN('Financials Cashflow Year'!$C30:$M30)),2)-2)}
```

The IF function gets an array of column numbers where the row's value is above zero.

Then the 2 parameter of the Small function, will bring back the value of the cell in the second most left columns whose value isn't zero.

I.e. in your example above it would bring back the 3, similarly if you changed the parameter to 1 it would bring back the 4.

The If statement gets the column numbers for the values in the index above zero.

**Note**: Hit the combination Ctrl + Shfit + Enter to submit rather than just enter
**Note2**: I noticed you are working across a row so I think you need the ",1," before the SMALL

Answer (score 0):

```
=INDEX(C30:M30,MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(C30:M30<>0,),0)+1)
```

Would give you the value of the cell one to the right of the first formula, but since it looks like you're looking for something more dynamic, this wouldn't work out incredibly well, for the cell two to the right of the first formula, you'd need this:

```
=INDEX(C30:M30,MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(C30:M30<>0,),0)+2)
```

Your best bet for grabbing out all cells to the right of the shown formula would be either transposing and filtering or using VBA, example for VBA:

```
Sub toRightOfZeros()

    Dim rng, cell As Range
    Dim startCellCol, destCellLocX As Integer
    Dim ValsArr() As String
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim foundNotZero As Boolean

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    destCellLocX = 1
    foundNotZero = False

    With wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
        Set rng = .Range(.Cells(30, 3), .Cells(30, 13))
    End With

    For Each cell In rng
        If foundNotZero = False Then
            If Not cell.Value = 0 Then
                foundNotZero = True
                startCellCol = cell.Column
                Exit For
            End If
        End If
    Next

    With wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
        Set rng = .Range(.Cells(30, startCellCol), .Cells(30, 13))
    End With

    For Each cell In rng
        With wb.Sheets("Sheet2")
            .Cells(1, destCellLocX).Value = cell.Value
        End With
        destCellLocX = destCellLocX + 1
    Next

End Sub
```

Input(In C30:M30): `0 0 0 0 365 788 940 239 12 0 99`

Output(On Sheet 2): `365 788 940 239 12 0 99`